# How to let a file run at night?

Tags: php, time

I got a script on my site, but that need to load every night at 00:00.

I tried using an cronjob

Cronjob run at night php hoi.php

But it wont run it ?

Also I don't know how to set it up

Any one know how to fix that it will run every night at 00:00

Comment: Have you tried to find a tutorial using Google? There are plenty of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in a terminal type:

```
crontab -e
```

edit the file / insert this line:

```
0 0 * * * php /complete/path/to/file/hoi.php
```

save and close the editor

file runs every night

Comment: Its on an webhost but i assume that , that is the same only looks else, i will try tho use it with that code

Comment: should work, if not feel free to ask again!